# Why does git-describe prefix the commit ID with the letter 'g'?

Tags: git

Typical output of `git-describe` looks like

```
some-tag-32-gf31f980
```

where `some-tag` is a tag name, `32` means that the described commit is 32 commits after the commit with that tag, and `gf31f980` means that the commit ID is uniquely abbreviated to `f31f980`.

My question is about the `g` in `gf31f980`.  Why is it there?  My first thought was that it is inserted to disambiguate parsing of the output of `git-describe`.  But I can't think of any case in which it actually helps to have it.  For example, the `32` component might be omitted, and there is no way to know that the output above describes a commit 32 commits after the tag `some-tag`, rather than the commit *at* the tag `some-tag-32`.  But the `g` doesn't help with this.

A regex match to extract just the commit ID can search for `/-g([0-9a-f]+)$/`.  There is no easy way to simplify this; you can't do `/-g(.*)$/` for example because that might erroneously match a `g` in the tag name. Without the `g` you could still do `/-([0-9a-f]+)$/`, so the `g` isn't helping you there.  Non-regex parsing processes will behave similarly.

The `g` is generated explicitly; the relevant source code (around line 240 of `builtin/describe.c`) is:

```c
static void show_suffix(int depth, const unsigned char *sha1)
{
        printf("-%d-g%s", depth, find_unique_abbrev(sha1, abbrev));
}
```

It's hard to search for information about this, because the relevant term, `g`, is a stopword.

What's the `g` for?

Comment: FYI, using `git grep -E "\bg\b" Documentation/git-describe.txt` in the [Git repo](https://github.com/git/git) returns the relevant line as the 2nd result. The same with plain `grep -E "\bg\b" Documentation/git-describe.txt`. The regex pattern `\b` [denotes the boundary between a word and a non-word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which will match things like `"g"` and `blah g blah`. [Regexes FTW!](https://xkcd.com/208/) Before there was Google, there was `grep` `;)`

Comment: I came here wondering exactly what the OP asked. Whilst I did get an explanation from the answers, I find the reasoning silly, so I am going to ask for further clarification/discussion here (sorry to resurrect the topic). 
If the `g` is really to disambiguate git from other scm software, surely the other parts of the output need the same. It won't be just the commit sha that differs - another scm might not have the same tags at all, and might have completely different number of commits. So still seems useless to me, especially in the middle of things, blending in so well.

Comment: @Anly I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67957132/6309) to address your comment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Jesse Luehrs immediately pointed out on Twitter](https://twitter.com/doyster/status/472065787944255488) that this question is answered in the [`git-describe` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html#_examples):

> The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is
>          used to allow describing the version of a software depending on the SCM the software is
>          managed with.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the g?

Comment: @Gqqnbig you can use sed, something like `git describe ... | sed 's/g\([^g]\{1,\}\)$/\1/'`. Match the last `g` and keep the rest until EOL

Answer (score 3):

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), there is a bit more on that "`-g`" prefix (which has been introduced in [Git v1.1.0, commit 908e531, Dec. 2005](https://github.com/git/git/commit/908e5310b958619559d34b0b6da122f058faa47e):

See [commit bfe35a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfe35a61653c5789c9038b3fe9925941cf10f623) (17 May 2021) by [Anders Höckersten (`ahockersten`)](https://github.com/ahockersten).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8c6dc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8c6dc2a5a5ce79356cdfcfe6dd624d95ff4eafd), 10 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`describe-doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfe35a61653c5789c9038b3fe9925941cf10f623): clarify default length of abbreviation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Anders Höckersten</sup>

> Clarify the default length used for the abbreviated form used for commits in git describe.
>
> The behavior was modified in Git 2.11.0, but the documentation was not updated to clarify the new behavior.

`git describe` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bfe35a61653c5789c9038b3fe9925941cf10f623/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L66-L69):

> Instead of using the default number of hexadecimal digits (which
> will vary according to the number of objects in the repository with
> a default of 7) of the abbreviated object name, use `<n>` digits, or
> as many digits as needed to form a unique object name.

`git describe` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bfe35a61653c5789c9038b3fe9925941cf10f623/Documentation/git-describe.txt#L143-L147):

> The hash suffix is "-g" + an unambigous abbreviation for the tip commit
> of parent (which was `2414721b194453f058079d897d13c4e377f92dc6`). The
> length of the abbreviation scales as the repository grows, using the
> approximate number of objects in the repository and a bit of math
> around the birthday paradox, and defaults to a minimum of 7.

---

> If the `g` is really to disambiguate git from other SCM software, surely the other parts of the output need the same. It won't be just the commit SHA that differs - another SCM might not have the same tags at all, and might have completely different number of commits. So still seems useless to me, especially in the middle of things, blending in so well.

The primary purpose of the `g` prefix is not to disambiguate Git from other SCM systems at a high level (e.g., comparing Git tags to Subversion revisions or Mercurial changeset IDs).
Instead, its role is more specific to Git's ecosystem. It helps to identify that the following hash is a Git commit hash when the `git-describe` output is used in various contexts, such as software versioning, build processes, or documentation.

The `g` acts as an indicator of Git's versioning scheme, especially in contexts where Git hashes are included in names, tags, or versions of software artifacts.
By using a character that cannot appear in the SHA itself, Git's developers ensured that the `git-describe` output remains clear and unambiguous, even in automated parsing scenarios.

The `g` prefix serves as an extra layer of specificity. In complex or automated environments where multiple tools and versioning schemes might intersect, that helps to prevent confusion and to make sure scripts or tools parsing version strings understand the nature of the identifier they are working with.

---

> Can you give an example of an automated system that makes use of the `g` prefix? Perhaps examples of alternative schemes (other prefixes other than `g`)?"

Imagine a deployment script that performs additional verification or logging if the version identifier includes a Git commit SHA, explicitly identified by the `g` prefix. That could be useful for distinguishing between production-ready versions (tagged without commits ahead) and versions that are ahead of the last tag, potentially indicating a development or test build.

```bash
VERSION_TAG=$(git describe --tags)
# Example VERSION_TAG might be: v1.2.3-45-g67890ab

# Extract the part after the 'g' to get the commit SHA
COMMIT_SHA=${VERSION_TAG#*-g}

if [[ $VERSION_TAG == *"-g"* ]]; then
  echo "That version is identified by a specific Git commit SHA: $COMMIT_SHA"
  # Perform additional checks or logging
  # For instance, make sure this commit has passed all tests in the CI pipeline
  verify_commit_status $COMMIT_SHA
else
  echo "That version does not include a specific Git commit SHA."
  # Handle tagged releases differently, perhaps with less scrutiny or different deployment targets
fi

# Continue with deployment or other actions
```

In practical terms, differentiating between versions with and without the `g` prefix (and thus directly tied to a specific Git commit) can help automate decisions around deployment, testing, and release management.
For instance:

- Versions that include a Git SHA (with the `g` prefix) might be deployed to a testing environment or marked as development versions.
- Versions without the `g` prefix (implying they are directly associated with a tag) could be considered stable releases and deployed to production.

That use of the `g` prefix enables a more nuanced approach to automation, where the deployment script can make informed decisions based on the version identifier's structure.

#### Hypothetical Alternative Prefix Scheme

Imagine a hypothetical deployment tool, **DeployMaster**, designed to manage software releases across different environments (development, staging, production) and stability levels (snapshot, beta, stable). **DeployMaster** introduces a prefix scheme in its version identifiers to encode this information directly:

- **Prefixes**:

  - `d-` for development snapshots.
  - `b-` for beta releases.
  - `s-` for stable releases.

When **DeployMaster** prepares a software version for deployment, it assigns a version identifier based on the software's current state and the target environment.
It might look like:

- `d-1.2.3-20240321.1`: A development snapshot of version 1.2.3, created on March 21, 2024, first snapshot of the day.
- `b-1.3.0-rc2`: The second release candidate of the 1.3.0 beta release.
- `s-2.0.0`: A stable release of version 2.0.0.

An automated deployment script using **DeployMaster** could use these prefixes to make deployment decisions, similar to the Git example but with a broader scope:

```bash
VERSION_ID=$(deploymaster current_version)
PREFIX=${VERSION_ID:0:2}

case $PREFIX in
  d-)
    # Development snapshot; deploy to a development server
    deploy_to_development $VERSION_ID
    ;;
  b-)
    # Beta release; deploy to a staging environment for pre-release testing
    deploy_to_staging $VERSION_ID
    ;;
  s-)
    # Stable release; deploy to production
    deploy_to_production $VERSION_ID
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown version type: $VERSION_ID"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

While Git's `g` prefix specifically marks commit SHAs in `git-describe` outputs, the concept of using prefixes to convey additional metadata about software versions is broadly applicable across different tools and systems.

---

> Also, I find it particularly strange that the `git describe` documentation says "Give an object a **human readable** name based on an available ref". And yet, by default and without a way to turn it off, it sneaks in a letter that confuses the humans.

The term "human readable" in the context of `git describe` means providing an identifier that is easier to understand and remember than a 40-character SHA-1 hash. Tags, which often correspond to version numbers, along with a relative commit count and a short SHA, make these identifiers more meaningful and easier to refer to during development and deployment processes.

However, the choice to include a `g` in the output was a deliberate technical decision, reflecting a trade-off between human readability and the need to avoid ambiguity.
The `g` stands out because it is the first letter after `f` in the hexadecimal sequence (`0-9`, `a-f`), and as such, it cannot appear in any SHA-1 hash. That makes it an ideal delimiter or marker to clearly indicate that the following characters represent a git commit SHA.
The `g` also makes sure the string can be uniquely identified as a Git commit identifier, differentiating it from other hexadecimal strings that might appear in a context where Git and non-Git identifiers coexist.

For scripts and automated systems that parse the output of `git describe`, the `g` provides a reliable way to extract the commit SHA from the string. As illustrated above, that parsing is important in continuous integration/continuous deployment (CI/CD) pipelines, where precise identification of software versions is necessary for automated testing, building, and deployment.

Git's design philosophy often prefers convention over configuration, opting for defaults that serve the needs of most users. While the `g` prefix is fixed and non-configurable, it represents a balance between readability and technical necessity. The decision to include it by default, without an option to remove it, underscores its role in maintaining consistency and reliability in identifying commits.

The trade-off here reflects a broader theme in software development tools and practices: finding the right balance between making tools accessible and understandable for humans, while also making sure they are precise, reliable, and unambiguous for automated processes.

Comment: Thank you for combining all this information! Can you give an example of an automated system that makes use of the `g` prefix? Perhaps examples of alternative schemes (other prefixes other than `g`)?

Comment: Also, I find it particularly strange that the `git describe` documentation says "Give an object a **human readable** name based on an available ref". And yet, by default and without a way to turn it off, it sneaks in a letter that confuses the humans.